# Download and upload file from react native webview

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webview

in my project i used react netive webview android for showing my web,, my web can upload and download data but when i click the button download from my app nothing happen but when i try in google chrome it's fine, the file is downloaded nicely.

what should i do for allowing download data inside webview? for upload i solved by using modul https://github.com/martinarroyo/react-native-webview-file-upload/ but i dont know about download.

any tips?

thank,

Junius

Answer (score 0):

if webview and android webview don't allow downloading data, then it is probably not possible